# using 'yo' instead of 'estoy'

Tags: verbos

I have just started learning Spanish and in my reference book I saw a conversation that went like this:

> - Yo un poco cansado ¿y ustedes?
> - Yo muy bien.

I would think that you had to say: "**Estoy** poco cansado", and "**estoy** muy bien". Is there something here I've missed? Don't you need a verb?

Answer (score 12):

**ESPAÑOL - (English follows)**

El verbo, como el sujeto, puede ser omitido en ciertas situaciones, sobre todo al responder a otra frase.

En tu ejemplo:

¿Cómo estás [tú]? - *How are you?*
[Yo] [estoy] un poco cansado. ¿Y ustedes? - *[I] [am] a bit sleepy. ¿And you (plural)?*

---

**ENGLISH**

The verb, like the subject, may be omitted in certain situations, especially when responding to another sentence.

In your example:

*¿Cómo estás [tú]?* - How are you?
*[Yo] [estoy] un poco cansado. ¿Y ustedes?* - [I] [am] a bit sleepy. ¿And you (plural)?

Comment: +1 for both language examples.

Answer (score 3):

I live in Spain and often hear this sort of statement. It's similar to the English,

> - How are you?
> - Me? Tired

You hear things like,

> - ¿Que quieres tomar?
> - Yo una caña

Answer (score 1):

As a rule of thumb, in Spanish you only use the subject when (at least) one of these happens:

- There is a change of subject.
- There is an emphasis on the subject (i.e. it is that person, and not anyone else).

In your example it looks like you have a combination of both.

Comment: I think that the OP is asking about the absence of a **verb**, not about the absence of a subject.

Answer (score 1):

In the Spanish language you can omit the verb in these constructions simply because it allows for faster, less "redundant" exchanges. It's not unlike English: 
--"Hey, how are you doing?"
--"Good; how about you?"
--"Alright."

Answer (score 1):

I think that in those examples there's a comma missing. It's called elliptic comma (I guess, as it's "coma elíptica") in Spanish.  http://www.gramaticas.net/2012/05/ejemplos-de-coma-eliptica.html

When you hear it spoken, there's a short pause, sort of equivalent to the one indicated by the question mark in English as @Andy said

Answer (score 0):

There was a punctuation error. Which it is crucial for understanding the semantics in the context that wants to be expressed:

1. One subject does not want to talk. The other answering subject (whether old or young) seems all right.

   - Yo. Un poco cansado. ¿Y usted?
   - Yo. Muy bien.
2. One subject is distracted and does not want to talk.  The other answering subject (whether old or young) seems all right.

   - Yo... Un poco cansado. ¿Y usted?
   - Yo. Muy bien.
3. One subject is surprised that the other person is asking but does not want to talk.  The other answering subject (whether old or young) seems all right.

   - ¡Yo! Un poco cansado. ¿Y usted?
   - Yo. Muy bien.
4. First subject is distracted and surprised of the second subject's question but does not want to talk. The second subject answers with a surprise too and depending of the expressions/ relations it may be inferred a sarcasm of the second subject.

   - ¡Yo...! Un poco cansado. ¿Y usted?
   - Yo... Muy... bien.

To summarize, you may write with or without 'yo' and replace it for 'estoy'. However, punctuation is a key factor to express even the mood of a subject. There are many other punctuation ways that I did not mention.

NOTE: You made a mistake with the sentence structure and I quote:

- Yo un poco cansado. ¿Y ustedes?
- Yo muy bien

INSTEAD,

- Yo un poco cansado. ¿Y USTEDES?
- NOSOTROS muy bien

OR,

- Yo un poco cansado. ¿Y USTED?
- YO muy bien

OR

- Yo un poco cansado. ¿Y USTEDES? [1ST SUBJECT]
- YO muy bien [2ND SUBJECT]
- YO muy bien [3RD SUBJECT]